# DomainDataSource + DomainService

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services, domainservices, domaindatasource

Is it possible to use the DomainDataSource control with a plain DomainService? I want to page/sort non-entity data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you build your DomainService, it will become available as a DomainContext. then you can use it inside your DomainDataSource.DomainContext property. A simple example from MSDN

```
<riaControls:DomainDataSource Name="source" AutoLoad="True" QueryName="GetProducts">
    <riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
        <domain:ProductDomainContext />
    </riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
</riaControls:DomainDataSource>
```

Comment: I had to reinstall riaservices to get this working, which is where my frustrations were coming from.

Comment: I can understand. It also took me a while and 3 times retrying after having no time to further try it out.